# How to increment numeric column based on other column in the same table in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have searched a lot to find the easiest way to develop this without using temp table as it has its own disadvantages, but could find an answer.

I have a table that the transactions of all the branches of a company will be saved in there.

Example :

```
Branch    FormNumber
   A         1
   B         1
   A         2
   A         3
```

I have a `formNumber` column that must start from 1 and automatically increases by one for each new record that will be saved for each branch.

I wonder how I can automate generating the form number based on the branch.

I tried to use after insert trigger but it can't use the same table to find the last `FormNumber` of current `Branch`.

I am using SQL Server 2016.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Use ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Branch order by FormNumber) in your insert statement

Comment: Can you add a composite key for the ID of the Branch and the ID of the FormNumber?

Comment: @Jacob, Unfortunately there is another ID field that the primary key is on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the above comments I came to conclusion to do add the following after insert and it worked.
Thanks all

```
declare @MaxFormNum int

SELECT  @MaxFormNum = MAX([FormNo]) + 1 
    FROM  [dbo].[Table1] 
    WHERE   BranchID =  @BranchID

UPDATE  [dbo].[Table1] 
SET     [FormNo] = @MaxFormNum
where ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you add a new row, you can use this insert query:

```
INSERT INTO your_table(Branch, FormNumber)
SELECT "A", MAX(FormNumber) + 1 
FROM your_table
where your_table.Branch = "A"
```

it will increase in one the column FormNumber.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I just want to update the previously inserted row , your statement will add a new record